# how to get group with max user with group's name in cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

here is my cypher query:

```
params.put("query", "name:*");
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( "start n=node:groups({query}) 
match n<-[:Members_In]-x 
with n,count(distinct x) as numberOfUsers 
return  max(numberOfUsers)", params );
```

`n` is the group name and x is the users of each group.
how can I get the group with the max number of user with its name?
Thanks.

Comment: with n,count(*) as numberOfUsers 
return  n.name,numberOfUsers order by numberOfUsers  desc limit 1;

Comment: if i have two groups with the same num of users and max number of users,what can i do?

Comment: @user1878364 What behavior do you expect if two groups have the same number of users? Return both?